# Date conversion from Central time to UTC in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am writing an XSL file and need to convert the Central time to UTC time using XSL templates. Any suggestions. TimeStamp: 20120113T100643-0600

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 1.0, I would suggest using the [EXSLT extensions for processing dates and times](http://www.exslt.org/date/). The best way to do this, and the limitations thereof, depend on what XSLT processor you're using.

If you're using XSLT/XPath 2.0, you can use the built-in function [adjust-date-to-timezone()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-adjust-date-to-timezone).